# Uneven floors from settling rim joist

Tags: floor, foundation, joists

We're trying to fix the uneven floors in our 850 sqft, 80 year-old house in San Jose. Our contractor opened up the floors and the problem appears to be that the floor joists rest on a skid, while the rim joist rests on the foundation, and there's ~1" difference between the surface of the skid and the surface of the foundation. See photo below.

Any ideas on the right way to level the rim joist with the floor joists? How expensive would you expect a good solution to be? Is inserting shims around the rim joist an option? (I think that would require jacking up the wall...)

Thank you for your thoughts!

[image]

Comment: The “skid” appears to be notched. Is the rim joist (and presumably the foundation) really settling?

Comment: Cost is not something we can answer... location and many other factors get in the way.

Comment: You are showing the bottom of the joists. Are the tops of the joists offset by the same amount?

Comment: Yes this 1" difference is on the top of the joists too, this just seemed like a clear way to convey it.

Comment: 1” is a lot of settling is it only on this 1 wall? Or a section of 1 wall? What kind of siding is on the house? I ask about siding because stucco is popular in that area and jacking the rim may cause a lot of cracking in the stucco, I would want a solid Cedar board to support the rim and probably add earthquake straps to keep the home on the foundation for the next big quake.